# How do I get rid of google scholar recommendations

Tags: google-scholar

I find google scholar recommendations for me to read to be of very poor quality. They are also distracting and are seldom refreshed. How can I disable this function or have the recommendations hidden?

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities:

1.) Open [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/), open the left-hand menu and click on *Alerts*. You will then see a list of all alerts you receive. Click on "CANCEL" in each row.

2.) If you wish to cancel a specific alert: At the bottom of each alert e-mail, there is a link called "CANCEL ALERT". Click on it and confirm that you wish to cancel it.

Comment: This is about alerts, but the question was about recommendations. Recommendation are shown on Google Scholar's title page.

Comment: Thank you, @lighthousekeeper, for clarifying. I thought it was about the e-mail alerts that recommend the `related research` of selected scholars.